# Getting a list of XML tags in file, using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, tags, elementtree, tagname

As mentioned, I need to get the list of XML tags in file, using library `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

I am aware that there are properties and methods like `ETVar.child, ETVar.getroot(), ETVar.tag, ETVar.attrib`.

But to be able to use them and get at least name of tags on level 2, I had to use nested for.

At the moment I have something like

```
for xmlChild in xmlRootTag:
    if xmlChild.tag:
        print(xmlChild.tag)
```

Goal would be to **get a list of ALL, even deeply nested XML tags** in file, eliminating duplicates.

For a better idea, I add the possible example of XML code:

```
<root>
 <firstLevel>
  <secondlevel level="2">
    <thirdlevel>
      <fourth>text</fourth>
      <fourth2>text</fourth>
    </thirdlevel>
  </secondlevel>
 </firstlevel>
</root>
```

Comment: Fantastic D's solution works fine, but there is a closing ) missing: elemList = list(set(elemList)) The order of the elements is neither the order of appearance nor level nor alphabetic.

Comment: @Helen Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer with your suggestion. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've done more of a research on the subject and found out suitable solution. Since this could be a common task to do, I'll answer it, hence I believe it could help others.

What I was looking for was etree method iter.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
# load and parse the file
xmlTree = ET.parse('myXMLFile.xml')

elemList = []

for elem in xmlTree.iter():
    elemList.append(elem.tag)

# now I remove duplicities - by convertion to set and back to list
elemList = list(set(elemList))

# Just printing out the result
print(elemList)
```

## Important notes

- `xml.etree.ElemTree` is a standard Python library
- sample is written for `Python v3.2.3`
- mechanic used to remove duplicities is based on converting to `set`, which allows only unique values and then converting back to `list`.

Comment: xmlTree.iter() does not seem to work for Python 2.6.9, I had to switch it to xmlTree.getiterator()

Answer (score 9):

You could use the built-in Python set comprehension:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlTree = ET.parse('myXMLFile.xml')
tags = {elem.tag for elem in xmlTree.iter()}
```

If you specifically need a list, you can cast it to a list:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlTree = ET.parse('myXMLFile.xml')
tags = list({elem.tag for elem in xmlTree.iter()})
```